# How does paperclip works with storage adapters such as S3 or dropbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, dropbox

Just wanted to know how does paperclip adapters handle files when a user uploads them. Does it:

1. uploads the files to the app file storage first, THEN drop them in S3 or dropbox. cause thats whole lot cost of bandwidth.
2. uploads the files from the user directly to S3 or dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is first uploaded to your server, then it's moved to Dropbox or S3 storage. It couldn't be different, because those libraries are embedded in your model and the model is managed by your application. The target of the form points to your server and the upload to Dropbox/S3 is completely hidden to the user.

If you want to upload directly to them, you should provide a separate uploader in the form and submit the reference. Of course, assuming Dropbox and S3 allows you to securely perform an upload in this way. I know that with S3 it's possible, I have no idea with Dropbox.

Comment: I see, so that means it will in fact double bandwidth costs unless I use a separate uploader. Hmmm, thanks a lot!